# Facebook login as a page in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

How can I logging as a page admin in android, like in the JS SDK? (Followed by this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the manage_pages permission to the ones you're requesting for the Session, and then make graph Requests as shown in the page you linked to (using the [Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request) object).

The workflow would then be:

1. ask the user to login (via a Session.openActiveSession, or using the login button)
2. ask for manage_pages permissions (via a session.requestNewPublishPermissions)
3. make a Request for "me/accounts" which should give you a list of pages the user administers
4. show the list to the user, and ask them which page they'd like to use
5. use that page_id to make further Requests

Comment: If I made that premission, the user have to select a page from his pages when login at first time?

Comment: edited my answer to include a workflow.

Comment: Great work flow, any chance for an updated example?

Comment: The only thing that changes in v4.x are steps 1 and 2, and there are pretty obvious replacements for each in the new SDK (checkout the LoginManager class).